# Scroll to bottom of FUIIndexTableViewDataSource-backed UITableView when new row is inserted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebaseui

I have a `UITableView` that is populated with a `FUIIndexTableViewDataSource`. When a new item is added to the `data source` I want to scroll to the bottom of the table view so that the user can see the new item. Is there a standard way to do this? I can't seem to find it.

Something like didInsertRow? I've tried searching "uitableview observe insert delete rows" and similar but can't find anything.

Comment: You should probably decide which of your two identical questions you want to keep, and delete the other one ...

Comment: good point, I deleted the other question.